# How to pass and return two-dimensional array from function in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am relatively new to c, and I still have not been able to find a good way of passing and returning a multi-dimensional array from a function. I found the following code, however it doesn't seem like a good way to do things because it passes the array and then to use it, it creates a duplicate with the malloc function. Is there a way to do it without the copying and malloc function, or a better way to pass and return an 2d array from a function in c in general? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int **matrix_sum(int matrix1[][3], int matrix2[][3]){
    int i, j;
    int **matrix3;
    matrix3 = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 3);
     
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        matrix3[i] = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 3);
    }
 
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            matrix3[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] + matrix2[i][j];
        }
    }
    return matrix3;
}
 
 
 
int main(){
    int x[3][3], y[3][3];
    int **a;
    int i,j;
 
 
    printf("Enter the matrix1: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            scanf("%d",&x[i][j]);
        }
    }
 
 
    printf("Enter the matrix2: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            scanf("%d",&y[i][j]);
        }
    }
 
 
    a = matrix_sum(x,y); //asigning
    printf("The sum of the matrix is: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            printf("%d",a[i][j]);
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 
    //free the memory
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        free(a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array are not copied for agurments. Just pointers to the first elements of them (`int[3]`) are passed.

To avoid `malloc()`, you should add another argument to specify the array where the result should be stored.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void matrix_sum(int matrix3[][3], int matrix1[][3], int matrix2[][3]){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            matrix3[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] + matrix2[i][j];
        }
    }
}



int main(){
    int x[3][3], y[3][3], a[3][3];
    int i,j;


    printf("Enter the matrix1: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            scanf("%d",&x[i][j]);
        }
    }


    printf("Enter the matrix2: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            scanf("%d",&y[i][j]);
        }
    }


    matrix_sum(a,x,y);
    printf("The sum of the matrix is: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            printf("%d",a[i][j]);
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An array can be declared and used through a reference (pointer)
for instance

```
char array[] = {'h','e','l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
char *pointer = array;
```

the way pointers work can be understood by calling sizeof() on a given type

```
printf("char:%d\nchar_pointer: %d\n", sizeof(char), sizeof(char*));
```

which results in the following output.

```
char:1
char_pointer: 4
```

these results mean that even though a char has 1byte, its pointer needs 4 in order to be stored in memory thus, they are not the same type.

now in order to pass an array as an argument to a function you have many options

```
void function1(array[4]) 
{
  //this function can receive an array of four elements and only four elements;
  //these types of functions are useful if the algorithm inside the function only works 
  //with a given size. e.g. matrix multiplication
}
//or

void function2(char array[], int size) 
{
  //this function can receive an array of elements of unknown size, but you can 
  //circumvent this by also giving  the second argument, the size.
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", array[i]);
    }
        
}
```

In order to use or call any of these functions you could pass the array or a pointer to the array

```
function2(array, 5);
function2(pointer, 5);
//these results are the same
```

The same applies to a multidimensional array

```
void function3(char** multi_dim_array, array_size_first_dim, array_size_second_dim);
//and you can call it by using the same syntax as before;

void main(int argc, char[] argv*) 
{
    char** multi_dim = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<=3 ; i++) 
    {
        multi_dim[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);    
    }
    
    function3(multi_dim, 3,4);
}
```

if you want to return a multidimensional array you can just return a pointer

```
char **malloc_2d_array(int dim1, int dim2) 
{
    char ** array = malloc(sizeof(char*)*dim1);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<=dim2; i++) 
    {
        array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * dim2); 
    }
    return array;
}
```

as a final note, the reason the code you found, copies the array, is because of functional programming(a way of programming if you will) where a function call cant modify its input, thus it will always create a new value;

Answer (score -1):

First of all this is not gonna be a technical explanation. I am just gonna try and explain what works not why.

For passing a multidimensional array you can use either an array with a defined size as you did in your example code:

```c
 void matrix_sum(int matrix3[][3])
```

Or if you don't want to use a defined size and want to take care of memory usage you can use a pointer to a pointer. For this case you also need to pass the size (unless you are passing NULL-terminated strings). Like this:

```c
void matrix_sum(int **matrix, int size)
```

BUT for this case you can't call the function with a "normal" array. You need to use a pointer to a pointer or a pointer to an array.

```c
int **matrix;
// make sure to allocate enough memory for this before initializing.
```

or:

```c
int *matrix[];
```

For returning an array you can just return a pointer to a pointer like you did in your code example.

But you don't need to return an array, because if you change a value in an array, (in a different function) the value will stay changed in every other function.
A short example for this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void    put_zeros(int matrix[][3])
{
    int i;
    int j;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 3)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j < 3)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

void    print_matrix(int matrix[][3])
{
    int i;
    int j;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 3)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j < 3)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
}

int     main(void)
{
    int matrix_first[3][3] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };
    print_matrix(matrix_first);
    put_zeros(matrix_first);
    print_matrix(matrix_first);
}
```

This will print "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" because that's the first value we assigned.
After calling put_zeros it will contain and print "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0" without the put_zeros returning the array.

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0
```